# Transform graph with matrix to graph with ArrayList

Tags: java, graph

I have a code of Graph with  adjacency matrix, I have to change it to a graph with  adjacency list, using ArrayList and comparable generics.

```
  public class Graph {

/**
 * edges[i][j] is the weight of the edge from i to j, or 0 if there is no
 * such edge.
 */
private double[][] edges;
private HashMap<Integer, String> names;

/**
 * The argument is the number of vertices in this Graph.
 */
public Graph(int vertices) {
    edges = new double[vertices][vertices];
    names = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        names.put(i, String.format("%s", 'A' + i));
    }

}

/**
 * Add an edge of weight 1 from i to j.
 */
public void addEdge(int i, int j) {
    edges[i][j] = 1;
}

/**
 * Add edges of weight 1 from i to j and from j to i.
 */
public void addUndirectedEdge(int i, int j) {
    edges[i][j] = 1;
    edges[j][i] = 1;
public double getCost(int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    if (edges[i][j] == 0.0) {
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    return edges[i][j];
}

/**
 * Return the weight of the edge from i to j.
 */
public double getEdge(int i, int j) {
    return edges[i][j];
}

/**
 * Return true if there is an edge from i to j.
 */
public boolean hasEdge(int i, int j) {
    return edges[i][j] != 0.0;
}
enter code here
```

So I change it.Instead double array, now it has array form ArrayLists, I thing I understand how to add Edge, but the other methods are now absolutely useless.

```
  class Graph<E extends Comparable<E>>
 {
private int numVertices;
private ArrayList<E> adjLists[];

Graph(int vertices)
{
    numVertices = vertices;
    adjLists = new ArrayList[vertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
        adjLists[i] = new ArrayList();
}

void addEdge(int i, E dest)
{
    adjLists[i].add(dest);
}
```

But I don't know what to do with the other methods. How can I find the cost or to make it work with undirected graph. Pls help.